# Meaning of words in sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

I can't understand the meaning of this sentence:

> You try to get your partner to make the phone call to place the
>   delivery order, and your partner does the same thing to you

What's the meaning of "get" and "place" ?
Is that mean: "make your partner to make phone call"?
I can't understand "to place the delivery order" part.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically means to leave a delivery order with the company. You are correct that it means make your partner to make phone call.

Comment: What about the word "place" ?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is part of an unfinished story.

You and your partner both want to buy something. To buy it one of you needs to call to order it from the supplier (that is, in the language of your question, 'to leave a delivery order' - not an expression that I as a native BrE speaker would ever use, by the way). You want your partner to make the call. Your partner wants you to make it.

Comment: What about the word "Place" ?

Comment: @KamranHosseini There is nothing wrong with 'place'. My problem was with 'delivery order'. In BrE at least one places an 'order' and arrangements for that order to be delivered are a separate transaction.